# Angular 2 add class conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

My target is to set or remove class depending on component boolean with Angular 2. For example: isRed = true > add class "red", if isRed = false > remove class "red". How is that possible? Code tried:

```
isRed: boolean;

constructor() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(window.location.hash) {

        } else{
            this.isRed = true;
        }
        if(scrollTop > 50) {
            this.isRed = true;
        }
        else  {
            this.isRed = false;
        }
    });
}
```

and html:

```
[ngClass]="{red: isRed}"
```

Comment: Your code should work, does it not?

Comment: Is the different variable naming in the constructor a copy/paste issue? If not `isRed` might be always undefined.

Comment: Can you please share more code (full class and template)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most concise way is IMHO

```
[class.red]="isRed"
```

**update**

The cause of your problem is `function` in

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
```

it should use arrow function

```
 $(document).scroll(() => {
```

otherwise `this` within the callback won't point to the current class, but instead to the caller.

I'd suggest you try to avoid jQuery with Angular2. Use instead

```
class MyComponent {

  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  isRed:boolean;

  @HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event:any) {
    var scrollTop = this.elRef.nativeElement.scrollTop;
    // or
    $(this.elRef.nativeElement).scrollTop();

    if(window.location.hash) {

    } else{
        this.isRed = true;
    }
    if(scrollTop > 50) {
        this.isRed = true;
    }
    else  {
        this.isRed = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `isRed` <-> `isRead` as mentioned by @Phillip

Comment: it is not from that

Comment: Then there is something else wrong - nothing in the code you posted.

Comment: @HostBinding('document:scroll', ['$event']) Support parameter did not match any signature of target

Comment: Sorry, should have been `HostListener` instead of `HostBinding`

Comment: I see, but `var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();` isn't going to work anyway. I updated my answer. I don't know if `element.scrollTop` returns the same as `$(element).scrollTop()`. If not you still might need to use jQuery.

Comment: scrollTop and elRef are undefined

Comment: Did you add the `constructor()`?

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to do with `scrollTop`. Change `this` to `var ` as it was in the code in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This is javascript so I would try something like:

```
isRed; // there's no need to initialize this variable
          since the constructor has its own scope but hey,
          do it if you wish so
```

Also it doesn't seem that you are working inside an object since you are using **;** instead of **,** which means that you shouldnt use "**:**" but rather "**=**"